# Check if feature is selected (Openlayers)

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, select

I wonder if there is a way to check whether a pointfeature (OpenLayers.Feature.Vector) is selected. I read the API, but didn't find any solution. Any idea?

Comment: See http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a feature is selected, it's added to the vector layer's `selectedFeatures` array (and removed after it's deselected)

---

You can test it in your browser: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-features.html

- Draw a polygon
- Open JS console (i.e. Firebug or Chrome dev tools)
- Type:

```
var vectorLayer = map.getLayersByName("Vector Layer")[0];
var feature = vectorLayer.features[0];
vectorLayer.selectedFeatures.indexOf(feature);

=>  -1 // (i.e. not selected)
```

- Select the polygon and check again:

```
vectorLayer.selectedFeatures.indexOf(feature)

=>  0 // (i.e. the polygon is selected)
```

Answer (score 2):

For newer Openlayers 3 the array is not kept in the Layer any longer. You can get by the interaction.select itself:

```
//get features as collection
var features=interaction_select.getFeatures();
//get length (.length doesnot work in my case)
var int_features=features.getLength();
//or access by numeric index like any collection
var first_item=features.item(0);
```

If you want to read more about interaction or the collection then just begin there: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html#getFeatures